# Getting error: Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this basic program that I've been experimenting with.

Here is my code:

```
def description1(self):
    desc = "%s is a %s, attack %s , health %s , defence %s , speed $s"%(self.name, self.description, self.attack, self.healthPoints, self.defence, self.speed)
    return desc
```

Here is the error message:

```
   line 9, in description1
    desc = "%s is a %s, attack %s , heath %s , defence %s , speed $s"%(self.name, self.description, self.attack, self.healthPoints, self.defence, self.speed)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: You have `speed $s`, presumable you meant `%s`. Because of the typo you only have 5 `%s` but 6 items in the tuple - hence the error.

Comment: Additionally the indentation is all off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in your format %s missed typed .
Below is the code with correct indent

```
class playerStats:
    name = ""
    description = ""
    attack = ""
    healthPoints = ""
    defence = ""
    speed = ""

    def description1(self):
        desc = "%s is a %s, attack %s , health %s , defence %s , speed %s"%(self.name, self.description, self.attack, self.healthPoints, self.defence, self.speed)
        return desc


#Defining playerstats for each of the Characters
stickNerd = playerStats()
stickNerd.name = "Stick Nerd"
stickNerd.description = "Nerd that only dreams of a 101%"
stickNerd.attack = "10"
stickNerd.healthPoints = "5"
stickNerd.defence = "5"
stickNerd.speed = "8"


print(stickNerd.description1())
```

Output

```
Stick Nerd is a Nerd that only dreams of a 101%, attack 10 , health 5 , defence 5 , speed 8
```

Even you can use

```
desc = "{name} is a {description}, attack {attack} , health {healthPoints} , defence {defence} , speed {speed}".format (name=self.name, description=self.description, attack=self.attack, healthPoints=self.healthPoints, defence=self.defence, speed=self.speed)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess Il pay more attention next time